# Does a Qt application work in Google Native Client?

Tags: c++, qt, browser, qt4, google-nativeclient

I'm not familiar with Qt or with [Google Native Client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Native_Client). Is it possible for a TRIVIAL Qt console application to be ported to Google Native Client? I understand that *some* work would be involved. But the question is, how much if it's even possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Qt developer has managed to get some Qt examples running under Native Client:
http://blog.qt.io/blog/2009/12/17/take-it-with-a-grain-of-salt/

Answer (score 4):

Qt now has an official Native Client SDK:

http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_for_Google_Native_Client

Comment: @SalmanPK I've heared that there is option to develop from Visual Studio for Windows. Otherwise, you can always end up in running Linux in Virtual Machine, there are plenty VM images ready to run. I hope you will find your way.

Answer (score 3):

Qt for Google Native Client Preview also updated here: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_for_Google_Native_Client

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't use system calls, you'd need to essentially port Qt to a new OS (ie, Native Client). This'll be a lot of work - good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested in using Qt with NaCl, I have made a Docker image containing Qt compiled with NaCl :

[Link to Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/r/theshadowx/qt5.4-nacl/)

You will just need to follow the instructions to get your application compiled.

There is also a video showing the process of compiling Qt with NaCl. At the end of this video, there is an example:

[Link to video of Qt compiled with NaCl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2pMv1Svtqw)

Hope this help